# merge data frames to eliminate missing observations

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames.  One (`df1`) contains all columns and rows of interest, but includes missing observations.  The other (`df2`) includes values to be used in place of missing observations, and only includes columns and rows for which at least one `NA` was present in `df1`.  I would like to merge the two data sets somehow to obtain the `desired.result`.

This seems like a very simple problem to solve, but I am drawing a blank.  I cannot get `merge` to work.  Maybe I could write nested `for-loops`, but have not done so yet.  I also tried `aggregate` a few time.  I am a little afraid to post this question, fearing my `R` card might be revoked.  Sorry if this is a duplicate.  I did search here and with Google fairly intensively.  Thank you for any advice.  A solution in base `R` is preferable.

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
  county year1 year2 year3
    aa     10    20   30
    bb      1    NA    3
    cc      5    10   NA
    dd    100    NA  200
", sep = "", header = TRUE)

df2 = read.table(text = "
  county year2 year3
    bb      2   NA
    cc     NA   15
    dd    150   NA
", sep = "", header = TRUE)

desired.result = read.table(text = "
  county year1 year2 year3
    aa     10    20   30
    bb      1     2    3
    cc      5    10   15
    dd    100   150  200
", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`aggregate` can do this:

```
aggregate(. ~ county,
          data=merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE), # Merged data, including NAs
          na.action=na.pass,              # Aggregate rows with missing values...
          FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)            # ...but instruct "sum" to ignore them.
##   county year2 year3 year1
## 1     aa    20    30    10
## 2     bb     2     3     1
## 3     cc    10    15     5
## 4     dd   150   200   100
```

Comment: `FUN=Filter, f = Negate(is.na)` would be another option for the function (would keep duplicates, which shouldn't happen anyway if OP specification are correct)

Comment: Excellent - a prime example of how base R has a lot of really neat and easily interpretable functions which are often overlooked.

Comment: Thank you.  Great answer.  Although, I think there needs to be a comma after na.pass.  I tried to edit the post and add the comma, but I guess edits have to be longer than one character.

Comment: @MarkMiller next time, edit the commented text too, to say what you're doing.  `# (added comma) Aggregate rows...`.  Gets you over the character limit, and decreases the "reject" votes.

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
m <- merge(df1, df2, by="county", all=TRUE)

dotx <- m[,grepl("\\.x",names(m))]

doty <- m[,grepl("\\.y",names(m))]

dotx[is.na(dotx)] <- doty[is.na(dotx)]

names(dotx) <- sapply(strsplit(names(dotx),"\\."), `[`, 1)

result <- cbind(m[,!grepl("\\.x",names(m)) & !grepl("\\.y",names(m))], dotx)
```

Checking:

```
> result
  county year1 year2 year3
1     aa    10    20    30
2     bb     1     2     3
3     cc     5    10    15
4     dd   100   150   200
```

Answer (score 2):

Another  option unsing `reshape2` and working in the long format :

```
library(reshape2)
## reshape to long format
df1.m <- melt(df1)
df2.m <- melt(df2)
## get common values
idx <- df1.m$county %in% df2.m$county & 
       df1.m$variable%in% df2.m$variable
## replace NA values 
df1.m[idx,]$value <- ifelse(is.na(df1.m[idx,]$value),
                            df2.m$value , 
                            df1.m[idx,]$value)
## get the wide format
dcast(data=df1.m,county~variable)

  county year1 year2 year3
1     aa    10    20    30
2     bb     1     2     3
3     cc     5    10    15
4     dd   100   150   200
```

Comment: Your answer is quite general.  For example, it still works if I change 10 to NA for county aa in year1 and delete year3 from df2.

Comment: @MarkMiller yes because it profit from the long format which uses just county as id (a key), other columns are just variables.